# Seaborn clustermap within subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I am trying to plot clustermap and box plots for a dataframe as subplots. I am having trouble plotting the clustermap as subplot as it is a figure level plot. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# initiliaze a dataframe with index and column names
idf = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), 
                               ('B', [4, 5, 6]), 
                               ('C', [10, 20, 30]), 
                               ('D', [14, 15, 16])], 
                               orient='index', columns=['x', 'y','z'])

# Get the figure and two subplots, unpack the axes array immediately
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

# Plot a boxplot in one of the subplot
idf.plot(kind='box', ax=ax1)

# Plot the clustermap in the other subplot
cax = sns.clustermap(idf, col_cluster=False, row_cluster=True)

# I tried to change the axis from the clustermap to subplot axis
# but I don't think this works like this
cax.ax_heatmap=ax2

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

What I am getting right now:

Image 1:

[image]

---

Image 2:
[image]

What I need is something like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Draw the clustermap, then add an axes to the figure and put the boxplot in there.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I tried to work with your solution and got something. I still need to understand more but right now I found a workaround from your suggestion. I am posting as an answer in case it's helpful to someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @mwaskom 's comment, I read more into the clustermap figure function and realized that I can just replace the column dendrogram image with the boxplot image. However, I would try to find how to add another axis instead of replacing the column dendrogram axis just in case I need to show both row and column dendrograms with the box plot. But what I got so far is fine with me. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# initiliaze a dataframe with index and column names
idf = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6]), ('C', [10, 20, 30]), ('D', [14, 15, 16])], orient='index', columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

# Plot the clustermap which will be a figure by itself
cax = sns.clustermap(idf, col_cluster=False, row_cluster=True)

# Get the column dendrogram axis
cax_col_dend_ax = cax.ax_col_dendrogram.axes

# Plot the boxplot on the column dendrogram axis
# I still need to figure out how to show the axis for this boxplot
idf.plot(kind='box', ax=cax_col_dend_ax)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

This results in:

[image]

Answer (score -5):

You should pass the ax as argument of the clustermap function:

```
cax = sns.clustermap(idf, col_cluster=False, row_cluster=True, ax = ax2)
```

As you can see from the documentation of the function clustermap (https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html), the actual function doing the plot is heatmap https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html which accept the ax as parameter.

Comment: Thanks. That was the first thing I tried but I was getting the error: http://paste2.org/YdtGPBUf